# webpack-dev-server making sockjs request on wrong port

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server, sockjs

For development, I'm starting my Node application on port 4000 and Webpack Dev Server on port 4001

```
process.env.NODE_DEBUG --> [undefined][false]
[INFO] Port '4000' is available for http server.
[INFO] Port '4001' is available for dev server statics.
Webpack: Starting ...
```

In our Node application, whenever a 404 is encountered, we generally retry that error. The issue that's happening is that I'm seeing is that a sockjs-node request is made to the wrong port which causes a cascading series of 404s as the application tries to retry the invalid sockjs url. What I can't figure out is why it's being made to port 4000 instead of 4001 in the first place.

[image]

Here is my webpack dev server config

```js
config.entry.client.unshift(`webpack/hot/only-dev-server`);
config.output = {
    path: paths.appBuildPublic,
    publicPath: 'localhost:4001',
    pathinfo: true,
    libraryTarget: 'var',
    filename: 'static/js/bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'static/js/[name].chunk.js',
    devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: info => path.resolve(info.resourcePath).replace(/\\/g, '/')
};
config.devServer = {
    disableHostCheck: true,
    clientLogLevel: 'info',
    compress: true,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    overlay: true,
    port: devServerPort,
    https: {
        ...createCertificate()
    },
    quiet: false,
    watchOptions: {
        ignored: /node_modules/
    }
};
config.plugins = [
    ...(config.plugins || []),
    new ErrorOverlayPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin({
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin(dotenv.stringified)
];
```

In my express router I've configured the following

```js
.use('/sockjs-node', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
        res.status(200).send();
    }
})
```

However, this is really a hacky way of solving the problem. Does anyone know why this sockjs request is made to my Node server instead of the webpack dev server? Any help would be really appreciated.